# Creating rownumber field in Access query on string field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a rownumber field in an Access (2003) query. I saw several examples using the `DCount()` function, but it is not clear how this can work on a table sorted according to a string field.

Could you help find find the correct syntax to do this? Here is an example of what I want to achieve.

Table 'test':

```
ID     Name
------------
1      aa bb
2      aa aa
3      bb bb
4      bb aa
```

I would like to obtain this table:

```
ID     Name     RowNum
-----------------------
2      aa aa    1
1      aa bb    2
4      bb aa    3
3      bb bb    4
```

I found that this query could help me obtain what I want:

```
SELECT test.ID, test.Name, DCount('test.Name','test','test.Name <=' & 'test.Name') AS RowNum
FROM test
ORDER BY test.Name;
```

However, I can only get this result:

```
ID     Name     RowNum
-----------------------
2      aa aa    4
1      aa bb    4
4      bb aa    4
3      bb bb    4
```

Could you help me with this query? Thanks a lot!

Comment: in Sql you want or MS Access

Comment: just replace DC count with ID instead of names  https://599cd.com/tips/access/140703-row-number/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since test.name is a string, you have to quote it properly:

```
SELECT
  test.ID,
  test.Name,
  DCount('test.Name','test','test.Name <= ''' & test.Name & '''') AS RowNum
FROM
  test
ORDER BY
  test.Name;
```

or use this if your test.name column could contain quotes:

```
DCount('test.Name','test','test.Name <= ''' & replace(test.Name, '''', '''''') & '''')
```

Comment: It works, thank you! Still one last thing. If I want these rownums in a query that works on a subset of my table using a WHERE clause, then the rownum is based on the rownum in the entire table, not the subset. Is there a way to get those rownums with a WHERE clause?

Comment: @Damien yes but you need to repeat the DCount: `WHERE DCount('test.Name','test','test.Name <= ''' & test.Name & '''')<=10` or with a subquery: `SELECT * FROM (the query above) s WHERE RowNum=3`

Comment: Why do I have to either choose DCount(...)<=10 or RowNum=3 for example? Let's say I have a list of names and I want to extract all the boys' names and sort them by alphabetical order, but only on the boy. How can I do?

Comment: @Damien oh sorry, I didn't read properly, you can modify your DCount, like this: `DCount('test.Name','test','test.sex=''Male'' AND test.Name <= ''' & test.Name & '''') AS RowNum` or dynamically, `DCount('test.Name','test','test.sex=''' & test.sex & ''' AND test.Name <= ''' & test.Name & '''') AS RowNum`

Comment: Yes! It works! Thanks a lot. I Just had to adapt it a bit since I used a Yes/no variable: `'test.sex= TRUE` Thank you again!